# how to avoid Locust treat 502 failed response as miniumum response time?

Tags: locust

once my website execeeds 1000 concurrent user, the nginx simplely return 502, but locust treat this reponse as miniumum response time? how can we avoid this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, is it not accurate? Are the 502s not being returned immediately with that 2ms response time? If that is accurate, I'm not sure you want to mess with the data.

But that being said, you certainly can mess with the data all you'd like. You can catch the response before it's automatically reported and change the data to what you want to report to Locust. You can read about how to do that in the docs here:

https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/writing-a-locustfile.html#validating-responses

If you need even more control, you can make it not report the response automatically at all (or just make your own http requests, using the Locust client) and then you can manually fire an event with complete custom data:

https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html#locust.event.Events.request_failure